# How to obtain B1/B2 for spouse of U.S citizen

Tags: immigration

I was born in The United States and I have lived in Ukraine for a long time. Well(over 2 years) I have lived here long enough to speak the language and get married.

I would like my family to meet my wife , but my wife and I don't want to move to the U.S , so I dont want to apply for immigration visa , but for just a tourist visa to visit my family.

How should I step? I heard that the embassy will try to force me to apply for immigration visa . Unfortunately , for me this is expensive.

Comment: So I thought I would add that despite being married to a citizen and wanting to stay in Ukraine she has been denied twice a tourist visa ...

So everyone know that marriage doesn't help at all get the visa.

Answer (score 2):

The US consulate will not try to "force" her to apply for an immigration visa. Presumably your wife does not want to immigrate to the US, so they wouldn't approve one even if she did apply.

If your wife can demonstrate strong ties to Ukraine, and that she will return to Ukraine after her visit to the US, there should be no problem applying for an receiving a visitor visa. The fact that you are a US citizen may help, but no guarantees.